# Make Collage of pictures and Editing (Layout,Background, Frames, Text,Filter)

Tags: java, android, image-processing

I would like to make an android app that has a photo collage and image editing in one app.

I have seen this library (https://github.com/fossasia/phimpme-android) but I'm unsure how to start.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Congratulations on your first question. I removed your statement about it being your first question so that the actual question was the focus. I expect that people will be equally kind, regardless of whether it is your first question or not. I also corrected some capitalisation and punctuation.

Answer (score 0):

phimpme-android is not a library...it's an app...so you need to **clone** or **download** this project in your android studio...to use this

To solve your problem...this  is a library that does editing of images and so on

Link : https://github.com/burhanrashid52/PhotoEditor

I hope this helped

Cheers

Comment: Brother i have downloaded phimpme-android. This app is using open cv tool.